# Backup software solution problem

Tags: c#

Good time of a day!

My team develop the soft to backup files to web storage. Now it has simle functionality - just take files from hdd, check date in local and remote file and update remote to new local.

The product owner want to to make backup in another way: on remote server replace only chenge peace of file. They want to make less traffic to storage (it's Amazon S3)

Now we have a next solution: brake file into peaces (4 kb each), count checksum of each peace, store this data in local db and at next backup verify checksums and transfer only changed peace.

But the metadata take much place on db if we backup a big amount of files

Can anybody have another solution? Thanks for help!

Comment: Depending on the type of files you are saving, a low-hanging fruit might be to compress it before sending it.  Instead of a chatty system that first has to interrogate the server for the state of the file before trying to determine differences.

Comment: why metadata occupies much more amount of memeory? what do you mean "metadata", is it just checksum + 4KB of the file that you already have ?

Comment: 1 checksum cant say for sure that this peace of file was not changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) uses [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) algorithm, so you might research that.